# Break line in div before stacking divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I want to design a responsive navbar using bootstrap. The problem is when I make the window small, the collapse icon moves from the top right below my "logo".

This is what the site looks like on a normal screen:
[image: normale size]

This is what it looks like on a mobile screen:
[image: mobile size unwanted stacking]

And this is how I would like it to look. The div should break the line before pushing the collapse button beneath itself:

[image: mobile size wanted]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>demo</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-4 py-md-5 px-sm-4 px-md-5" style="background-color: aquamarine">
            <div id="navbar-logo" class="logo ml-2" style="font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 10px;">
                PRENAME SURNAME
            </div>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="toogleMenuBackground()">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pt-3 pt-md-4 pt-lg-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">more</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">content</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above HTML in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvNZxq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would need to set the maximum width that this div can take.

You could either use a set value for the .logo size (if you know what size it is going to be), or alternatively use a bit more future-proof solution, where you say that you would like the .logo to take up to 100% of width reduced by the size of the navigation button (and all the margins), like here:

```
.logo {
    max-width: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

If you insist on not adding extra CSS and using just the Bootstrap classes, you could enforce `display:flex`. You would then add the following classes to your navigation: `d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-between`, so:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-4 py-md-5 px-sm-4 px-md-5 d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-between">
```

Comment: I used your first solution by setting the max-width. The second solution did work too in terms of displaying the title correct with a line break. But the problem was, that now the collapsable menu would appear next to the logo title and the collapse button instead of being beneath it. I guess it's because of `flex-nowrap`. Do you know a workaround for this?